# How to include a classfier on a tycho build artifact?

Tags: maven, classification, tycho

I am building an eclipse update-site using tycho. 
I would like to build the site **with all dependencies included**:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and the same site with **dependencies not included**:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includeAllDependencies>false</includeAllDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

For that I can use maven-profiles. (I am not providing code about profile definition here)

Now the problem is, that artifacts built with different profiles would have same names. 
My idea was to add a different classifiers dynamically, when building with different profiles.

**Is it possible to dynamically add classifiers to artifacts, build with tycho?** 
The resulting artefacts could have classifiers withalldependencies /withalldependencies and have following names:

```
my.updatesite-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-withalldependencies
my.updatesite-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-withoutalldependencies
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Not out of the box [according to docs](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-p2/tycho-p2-repository-plugin/archive-repository-mojo.html).

You may want to try

[build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) which allows to attach arbitrary files with classifiers

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to the OP's question as well. Your suggestion isn't what the OP is asking.  The OP wants to know how to add a classifier to the generated artifact, not how to add additional files to the artifact using a classifier.